# Iterating over a QVariant that is a QList<int>?

Tags: c++, qt, casting, qlist, qvariant

I'm using QObject's dynamic property to store information to be used in a Slot that can access said property. The sender is a QState with: `myQState->setProperty("key", QList<int>(0, 1, 2));`

I would like to convert the stored [QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html) back to a QList so it can be iterated. The following code does not work (error C2440: QVariant can't be converted to QList with {[T=int]):

```
QVariant vprop = obj->property("key");
QList<int> list = vprop; //   < - - - - - - - - ERROR
foreach (int e, list )
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << "" << e;
}
```

---

This code works. The object to set as property:

```
QVariantList list;
list.append(0);
list.append(1);
list.append(2);
```

And in the slot

```
QObject *obj = this->sender();
foreach( QByteArray dpn, obj->dynamicPropertyNames() )
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << "" << dpn;
}
QVariant vprop = obj->property("key");
qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << "" << vprop;
QVariantList list = vprop.toList();
foreach(QVariant e, list )
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << "" << e.toInt();
}
```

Comment: ok the code posted does not work at all..just a moment

Answer (score 5):

Or use `QList<QVariant> QVariant::toList () const`

```
QList<QVariant> list = vprop.toList();
```

And than iterate over the items and convert each to integer if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `QVariant::value`:

```
QList<int> list = vprop.value< QList<int> >();
```

Comment: Definitely the preferred way to do this IMHO.  You can now substitute any type you need to convert. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was posted Qt has started providing a more efficient way to iterate over a QVariant that contains an iterable value, like `QList<T>`, rather than converting all of it to a `QList<QVariant>`. You basically have to get the value of the QVariant as an QSequentialIterable:

```
QList<int> intList = {7, 11, 42};
QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue(intList);
if (variant.canConvert<QVariantList>()) {
  QSequentialIterable iterable = variant.value<QSequentialIterable>();
  for (const QVariant& v: iterable) { /* stuff */ }
}
```